# AppFabric development on Windows XP?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, appfabric

1. Installed app fabric x64 on Windows Server 2008.
2. Copied Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll from %windir%\System32\AppFabric [ref](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/add-a-reference-to-the-microsoft-applicationserver-caching-client-assembly.aspx) to Win XP Pro 32-bit dev machine.
3. Added reference to both these files in project
4. Added using `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;`
5. Cleaned solution
6. Receive error: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but you might want to check and see if the DLLs belong in the GAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you verify that you were using .NET framework >= 2.0?

```
Do not use the client profile for the target framework version. In Visual Studio 2008,
uncheck the Client-only Framework subset  checkbox. In Visual Studio 2010, select .NET
Framework versions that do not specify "Client Profile".
```

**See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790876.aspx)**

Comment: Ah, I was using the client profile framework.  Now everything compiles!