# AppFabric 1.1 for Windows server development with windows XP

Tags: appfabric, distributed-caching, appfabric-cache

I have installed and configured AppFabric 1.1 for Windows server on a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2.

I want to use the caching features from my 32 bit Windows XP development machine. How do i go about installing the Cache client components onto my XP machine?. MSDN documentation suggests that XP is not supported, and at the minimum, i need Vista.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [AppFabric development on Windows XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756482/appfabric-development-on-windows-xp)

Comment: Not sure if that post was about AppFabric 1.0 or 1.1

Comment: Not sure if the question was about 1.0 or 1.1, but the [setup seems to require the same DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334398(v=azure.10).aspx) for AppFabric 1.1 development. Unsure if they still work on XP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to install the [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client) package for client assemblies. You will see if it ok !